# Laravel MIX not working, using CDN does work

Tags: laravel, npm, laravel-mix, katex

I'm a bit lost here. I'm NOT new to Laravel Mix so this is really confusing.

I have a layout blade file and it looks something like this

```
<html> ....
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/KaTeX/0.9.0/katex.min.js"></script>
    <script src="{{ mix('/js/myjs.js") }}></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

The `myjs.js` is compiled using Laravel Mix and contains dozen of libraries and all of them compile and work properly.

However if I include this

```
require('katex'); //so it's above everything else to simulate situation from above, when it's included in the layout file
...
```

and drop the CDN script from the layout file - the Katex library won't work.

I tried using `require('katex/dist/katex.min.js')` but still nothing. The `katex.min.js` file in the library and the one in CDN are the same.

I'm not expert on npm and I only use it to fetch libraries and then merge and minify them in my Laravel app.

Can anyone help me pin point the problem here or point me to what am I doing/getting wrong here?

Shouldn't the

```
<script src="lib1.js"></script>
<script src="lib2.js"></script>
```

included in the html, and

```
require('lib1')
require('lib2')
```

compiled to

```
<script src="{{ mix('compiled.js') }}"></script>
```

produce the same thing?

Thanks!

UPDATE:

I'm using Katex to implement [this](https://github.com/tylerecouture/summernote-math) summernote plugin.

Comment: The short answer is : no they don't produce the same thing. Webpack bundles everything in its own scope but including scripts with the `<script>` tag includes them in the global scope. It will help us to understand what the problem is if you share how you're trying to use Katex inside your other scripts.

Comment: Thanks, give me a minute and I'll update the question. I was hoping I was missing something obvious.

Comment: You have to install `Katex` via a npm package. Laravel Mix do not work with CDN scripts, unless you want to use multiple `<script>` requests.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Yes I installed it as many other packages: `require('katex');` but it didn't work. I tried `window.katex = require('katex');` but still nothing. Maybe I needed to do it with big K. Hmm, let me try and get back to you.

Answer (score 0):

Katex should be installed as:

```
window.katex = require('katex');
```